# Why Python stores an array in a function this way?

Tags: python, list, function

I was checking tiny scripts and noticed this:

```py
def foo( a = [] ):
    a += [1]
    print(a)


foo() # prints [1]
foo() # prints [1,1]
foo() # prints [1,1,1]
```

Why does this happen instead of printing only `[1]`?

Comment: This has been answered many times https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: This is one of the tricky sharp edges in Python.  When you create your function, it creates an empty list object, and your default parameter is that SPECIFIC list object.  Every time you change it, the changes accumulate.  The right solution is `def foo( a=None):` and `if a is None:` / `a = []`.

Answer (score -3):

You basically append element to your list. For example [1] + [1] would be [1, 1].

Comment: Well yes, everybody sees that. The question was "why"?